# How much resources does an unremoved event listener consume?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

Let's say I've got an event listener function that is listening for an event that will *never* be called again throughout the lifespan of the program. The listening object will never need to be garbage collected.

How much memory does this use?
If it's negligible, I'd rather not remove the listener because having the `removeEventListener()` statement makes my code less readable.

Comment: So your code with this listener will never be used in any other code again?  To me that is the risk is that someone may copy this code, not realize that the removeEventListener is never called and so a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on how large and complex the listener is. In many cases, the memory impact is negligible, however, the object you're holding in memory may be keeping several other objects in memory. If one of them is a streaming video or something, it may be sucking on your memory, processor, and network.

You can also set useWeakReferences to true when you first add the event listeners. This makes the link between the listener and the event dispatcher weak so that the latter doesn't hold the prior in memory if it's deleted everywhere else. [More on that here.](http://dispatchevent.org/mims/creating-weak-references-in-as3/)

Still, it's never a good idea to leave objects in memory that are not going to be used again and there's no reason to avoid `removeEventListener()`. Striving for code readability before making it work correctly is never a good idea. If you're that concerned with the way your code looks, put the `removeEventListener()` calls inside a method called `cleanupUnusedListeners()` or something. Indeed, I would say that omitting it is less readable because when you're looking for the source of your memory leak, it will be harder to find the spot where you DIDN'T put a `removeEventListener()`. It may not be pretty but that's just the way it is, Jack.

Comment: I agree with Mims.  The larger the object that calls addEventListener or the more objects it has references to, the more memory the unremoved reference will hold on to.

Answer (score 0):

It's negligible, unless you have thousands of them. Check out how [EventDispatcher](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) works and take a look at it's source code.