# How can I remove an HTML5 video event listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, html5-video

I want to remove the following video event listener.

```
var video = document.querySelector("video");
video.onplay = function(){
//my operations
}
```

Now I want to remove/disable this listener. Is it possible to remove it like HTML5 DOM event listener:

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
element.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
```

The reason for removing is because, in a dynamic site like youtube, this event does not fire when I go to another video dynamically (especially on a channel's featured video page). I need to update my "video" variable on dynamic page change and set the event listener again. But I think this will affect the performance of the tab with time because the previous listeners are still there running (or are they?). I couldn't find an official documentation regarding this.

Comment: You can detect page navigation on youtube, see [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34077641)

Comment: Thank you for your help. One thing I haven't understood is, are the event listeners that were set previously still running or are they automatically discarded when the video elements they were attached to are gone? This might sound silly but I am new to this. Please bear with me. :)

Comment: Since the elements are removed there is nothing to trigger the previously assigned listeners so you can say the event subscription is automatically removed.

Comment: Sir, it turns out I still need to know if it's possible to remove the event listener I mentioned. I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397446/how-much-resources-does-an-unremoved-event-listener-consume)  and I've practically seen the effect of not removing them. My youtube tab would take up even above 600MB of memory, which normally never reaches 400MB.

Comment: Normally the event listener is unregistered automatically when the DOM element it's attached to is removed. However GC may fail if your listener does bad stuff like hoarding out-of-scope references. Anyway, instead of creating a new function each time you should declare just one [global] function and assign the reference to `onplay`.

Comment: `var play_message_sent = false;
video.onplay = function () {
 try {
  if (video.currentTime >= 0.3) {
  console.log("onplay " + video.currentTime);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({status: "played"});
  play_message_sent = true;
  }
 } catch (error) {
  console.log("onplay error caught :" + error.message);
 }
};` is the actually listener. Sorry I can't format this with newline.

Comment: play_message_sent is an out-of-scope variable which prevents garbage-collection of the listener so my previous comment fully applies.

Comment: I will do that and see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why? There'll be just one function object so no leaking would take place. However it may require reworking the code a bit.

Comment: My doubts are cleared now. Thank you again very much Sir.